# Generic linked list sorting function in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to sort a linked list of nodes. I go over each node in the list, compare it with the current head, if it's "larger" then I swap. Finally I recur with `head->next`. 
I want the function to return the "head" of the new sorted function.

The first problem is that it seems to get stuck in the first for loop.

Where have I gone wrong?

```
struct Node{
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
    int age;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node * sortList(struct Node * head, 
    int(*cmp)(struct Node *, struct Node *)){
    printf("Entered Sorting Function\n");
    struct Node * target;
    struct Node * p;
    struct Node * first;
    bool firstRun = TRUE;
    target=head;
    first=head;
    for (p=head; p!=NULL; p=p->next) {
        if ((*cmp)(p, target) == 1)
            printf("Comparing %s with %s\n", p->firstName, target->firstName);
            target = p;
    }
    if (head!=target) {
        printf("swapping nodes");
        swapNodes(head, target);
    }
    if (firstRun==TRUE) {
        first = head;
        printf("setting very first to: %s\n", first->firstName);
        firstRun = FALSE;
    }
    if (target->next != NULL) {
        printf("recurring with %s\n", target->next->firstName);
        sortList(target->next, cmp);
    }
    return first;
}
```

Update:

The problem in the first loop was missing braces around the statements in the `if`, as [nemetroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270654/nemetroid) pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27461438/15168) — thanks, nemetroid. The code should read:

```
    for (p=head; p!=NULL; p=p->next) {
        if ((*cmp)(p, target) == 1) {
            printf("Comparing %s with %s\n", p->firstName, target->firstName);
            target = p;
        }
    }
```

However, the sort is still not working.  What else is wrong?

I figured out that my swap isn't working, as people mentioned. Here is an updated code with the swap included.

UPDATE: I fixed the swap, now I only swap the contents of the nodes.

```
void swapNodes(struct Node * nodeA, struct Node * nodeB) {
    struct Node * tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    strcpy(tmp->firstName, nodeA->firstName);
    strcpy(tmp->lastName, nodeA->lastName);
    tmp->age = nodeA->age;

    strcpy(nodeA->firstName, nodeB->firstName);
    strcpy(nodeA->lastName, nodeB->lastName);
    nodeA->age = nodeB->age;

    strcpy(nodeB->firstName, tmp->firstName);
    strcpy(nodeB->firstName, tmp->firstName);
    nodeB->age = tmp->age;
}
```

But the sort is still not working, here is the current code for my sort:

```
void sortList(struct Node * head, 
    int(*cmp)(struct Node *, struct Node *)){
        if (head==NULL || head->next==NULL)
            return;
        int length = listLength(head);
        int i, j;
        struct Node * p = head;
        struct Node * q = p;
        bool firstRun = TRUE;
        for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
            if (firstRun != TRUE) 
                p=p->next;
            else if (firstRun == TRUE)
                firstRun = FALSE;
            for (j=i+1; j<length-1; j++) {
                q = q->next;
                if ((*cmp)(q, p) == 1) 
                    swapNodes(p, q);
            }
        }

}
```

I fixed it. Posted the sort code in an answer. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: 'Where have I gone wrong?' - not debugging the code/data.

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by hacking the question; update the question to show the partial fix.  I'll do it this time, to illustrate.

Comment: You'd need to show the body of `swapNodes()` because this call is at least suspicious: `swapNodes(head, target);`.  Normally, you'd need to pass pointers to the pointers you want to swap, but it does depend on what the code does.  The `firstRun` code is dubious too; you should simply be recording the return value from the recursive call in a suitable place (maybe `first->next = sortList(head->next, cmp);`).

Comment: I took that my swap works for granted. Apparently it isnt. I posted the body. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Your swap only swaps what comes after your elements. If `a->next == b` initially and you swap `b` with `x`, shouldn't `a->next == x` when you're done?

Comment: With the change you did to `swapNodes`, now `head` is always the actual head of the list, even after the swap. This should necessitate some changes.

Comment: Yes, I am redoing my sort code. But I am getting SegFault. I will post updated version. Could you spot the problem?

Comment: Your `swapNodes()` code allocates memory but doesn't free it — a memory leak. It could be fixed by `free(tmp);` before the end of the function, but it might be better to avoid it with `void swapNodes(struct Node *nodeA, struct Node *nodeB) { struct Node tmp = *nodeA; *nodeA = *nodeB; nodeA->next = tmp.next; struct Node *b_next = nodeB->next; *nodeB = tmp; nodeB->next = b_next; }`. The assignments to `nodeX->next;` preserve the original values. You might want to add `assert(nodeA != nodeB);` at the top. The code will work if you swap a node with itself, but you shouldn't do it. Untested code!

Comment: Your malloc and free usage is very confusing. You need to free precisely once for each time you malloc. Your code doesn't need either though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got it to work. Posted my sort code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I used, it seems to work so far. 
Note: We swap 2 nodes by swapping their contents, without manipulating the element they point to next.

```
void sortList(struct Node * head, 
    int(*cmp)(struct Node *, struct Node *)){
        if (head==NULL || head->next==NULL)
            return;
        int length = listLength(head);
        int i, j;
        struct Node * p = head;
        struct Node * q = p;
        struct Node * target = head;
        bool firstRun = TRUE;
        for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
            q=p;
            if (firstRun != TRUE) 
                p=p->next;
            else if (firstRun == TRUE) 
                firstRun = FALSE;
            target = p;
            while (q->next != NULL) {
                q = q->next;
                if ((*cmp)(q, target) < 0) 
                    target = q;
            }
            if (p!=target)
                swapNodes(p, target);   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the if statement lacks braces only the `printf("Comparing...` is conditional, so you are executing `target = p` on each iteration of the for loop. This is probably not what you intend to do.

Also, you probably want to do `first = target` and not `head`. That entire block is of dubious use though, it will run in each recursion step.

Comment: That's why it was getting stuck in the loop, correct. But that is not why it's not working. But I think I might have a clue. I'm in panic mode and yes, too much stress isn't too for accomplishing.